# What are the differences between query types?

Tags: sql

What are the differences between a `query`, a `sub-query`, and a `correlated sub-query`?

When should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

A subquery is a query in a query. This is used in IN clauses and EXISTS clauses for instance.

**Example 1:**

select x, y, (select max(z) from b) from a;

Here we are interested in one value from table b: the maximum z. Rather than joining the two tables, we use a subquery in the SELECT clause.

**Example 2:**

select * from a where a.x in (select y from b);

We select all records from table a where a corresponding record in b exists.

**Example 3:**

select * from a where exists (select * from b where y = a.x);

Again, we select all records from table a where a corresponding record in b exists.

Example 3 uses a **correlated subquery**. That means that inside that query we refer to a value from outside (a.x). Example 2 does the same with a non-correlated subquery.

As to "when it is needed": There are often several ways to get the desired data in SQL. Use the approach that you consider best (which is usually the most readable one). Sometimes this will involve subqueries, sometimes not, sometimes you will use correleted subqueries, sometimes non-correlated ones. It doesn't matter; use what's appropriate.